# Could not locate device support file for iOS 13.4.1

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

Hello I tried to build my unity project in Xcode but I have Xcode problem with
Could not locate device support file for iOS 13.4.1 (17E262)
my phone 11 pro max
Xcode version 11.3.1
my mac system 10.4.6
and when trying[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56joO.png) to upgrade Xcode to 11.4.1 it Requires macOS 10.15.2 or higher
and my mac cant upgrade to 10.15 cuz it mid-2010
hopefully, find a solution for that

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding [iPhoneOsSupport](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport). Download the required version of the support file from here and you should be able to run the project.

PS. currently there is no support file for 13.4.1 at the time I post the answer. What worked for me was I downloaded the 13.4 file and renamed it to 13.4.1 It works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Asis! You're a lifesaver.